# Using jquery within jquery Templates, is this possible?

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I want to perform an if check with in jquery template:

jquery template

```
<script id="CardWallItem" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <div id="lc${ProductId}" class="card">
        <input class="ItemId" type="hidden" value="${CardId}"/>
        <a href="" class="oCloseButton" onclick="return $$.laneItems.deleteLane(this);">x</a>
        if($.parent().find('.ItemId').val() == ${EntityId}){
        <p class="text" onclick="return $$.laneItems.editCard(this);">${Desc}</p> 
        <div class="edit bg" style="display:none;">
            <input class="editval" type="text" maxlength="20" />
            <a class="button" href="" onclick="return $$.laneItems.saveTitle(this);">Save</a> 
        </div>
        }
    </div>
    <br /><br />
</script>
```

and as you can see the if check in between, this one:

```
if($.parent().find('.ItemId').val() == ${EntityId}){
            <p class="text" onclick="return $$.laneItems.editCard(this);">${Desc}</p> 
            <div class="edit bg" style="display:none;">
                <input class="editval" type="text" maxlength="20" />
                <a class="button" href="" onclick="return $$.laneItems.saveTitle(this);">Save</a> 
            </div>
            }
```

as the output of this is that it is printing whole if statement on page. So can anyone please tell me what I should do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery template itself is any HTML markup, along with any of a set of template tags which enable some very rich scenarios for creating data-driven UI. The current set of tags that are supported in jQuery templates are:

```
- ${...}: Evaluate fields or expression
- {{each ...}}...{{/each}}: Iterate without creating template items
- {{if ...}}...{{else ...}}...{{/if}}: Conditional sections
- {{html ...}}: Insert markup from data
- {{tmpl ...}}: Composition, as template items
- {{wrap ...}}...{{/wrap}}: Composition, plus incorporation of wrapped HTML
```

And for more details and example please visit [here](http://www.borismoore.com/2010/09/introducing-jquery-templates-1-first.html).

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of conditionals in jquery templates is different:

```
{{if CONDITION}}

{{else}}

{{/if}}
```

See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-if/) of the if template tag.

Comment: {{ if($.parent().find('.ItemId').val() == ${EntityId}) }} some code {{/if}}, is this correct?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can access the dom there. Give it a try.